# What is the meaning of the title "Akad. Orat"?

Tags: career-path, germany, academic-history

What is the meaning of the German academic title "Akad. Orat"? What would its international analogous be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via @mkennedy in a comment:

Nontenured, approximately assistant professor in the US system.

Expands out to Akademischer Oberrat.

See: [Academic ranks in Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_ranks_in_Germany)

Comment: No, "Akademischer Oberrat" is generally tenured.

Comment: ...and not a professor (no supervision of PhD students, no W1/2/3 salary scale, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Akademischer Oberrat *is* typically tenured (in the sense of a lifelong position), so this is something between assistant professor and associate professor in the US system.

If he or she also got their Habilitation they are Privadozent/Privatdozentin, which would then compare to associate professor.

The Wikipedia article cited by Bryan is misleading in this point, as "Akademischer Rat" is a position that could be granted temporarily ("auf Zeit") or permanently ("auf Lebenszeit"). However, as "Akademischer Oberrat" is generally a promotion from "Akademischer Rat" that one could only get after quite some time on the job, it is very unlikely for the temporary position (which is limited to 6 years).